# How do I store IP addresses and CIDR Ranges effectively

Tags: algorithm, networking, data-structures, ip-address, cidr

I have a use case which I do not know how to solve. I am asking it here to get some guidance on what I need to learn to solve this.

- I need store IP addresses(lots of them, may be few hundred million). These can be as `1.1.1.2` or `CIDR` ranges like `1.1.1.1/24`

The requirement is following

```
- Save all the IP address which comes as above format in-memory
- Search should work as following  
   - if I have IP address as 1.1.1.2 and 1.1.1.1/24, it should match the specific IP address 1.1.1.2 and not the CIDR range it falls into (1.1.1.1/24)
   - If specific IP address is not found but CIDR range is available, CIDR range is returned
   - if no match is found, return null/throw exception
```

**Question**
- What data structure(s) can help me solve this problem? Tries? 
- what approach you would take?
- How to make sure it does not consume too much memory and search is fast (some reasonable trade-off will be there)

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you validate these. For example, `1.1.1.1/24` is not rally a valid range to compare to; the correct range would be `1.1.1.0/24`. You can `AND` the address with the mask to correct that one, but there are other validations that you want to do, too.

Comment: Don't even think about trying to convert something like this to IPv6.

Answer (score 6):

I would use a binary tree (this kind of trees are called [Radix Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)):

1. The bits of the IP address are used for navigating it starting from the MSB (e.g. 0 = left child and 1 = right child)
2. All specific IP addresses are leaves while CIDR ranges are internal nodes (using dummy leaves to indicate "missing" IP addresses just like in red-black trees)
3. Some nodes will be actual data that you have, other are only "navigation" nodes (they correspond to CIDR ranges you don't have, mark them with a flag)

Search: Simply navigate the tree with the address you have. If you end up in a leaf then you have that specific IP address otherwise the "lowest" node with a flag (see point 3) is the most specific CIDR range that  you have.

Example: let's work with 8 bits IP and 2 bit "sections" addresses; after inserting 1.1.1.0/6 the tree will be (the number after the IP is the "contains" flag, nils are dummy leaves)

```
    <root> -- nil
      |
00.00.00.00/1 (0) -- nil
      |
01.00.00.00/2 (0) -- nil
      |
01.00.00.00/3 (0) -- nil
      |
01.01.00.00/4 (0) -- nil
      |
01.01.00.00/5 (0) -- nil
      |
01.01.01.00/6 (1) --nil
      |
     nil
```

If you look for the IP address 1.1.1.1 you will stop at 1.1.1.1/6, which is a CIDR range because it has nil children and is the most specific (down in the tree) that there is. If you now insert 1.1.1.1 the tree will be

```
    <root> -- nil
      |
00.00.00.00/1 (0) -- nil
      |
01.00.00.00/2 (0) -- nil
      |
01.00.00.00/3 (0) -- nil
      |
01.01.00.00/4 (0) -- nil
      |
01.01.00.00/5 (0) -- nil
      |
01.01.01.00/6 (1) -- nil
      |
01.01.01.00/7 (0) -- nil
      |
01.01.01.01 (1)
```

1.1.1.1 does not have leaves because it is an IP address. Finally let's insert 1.1.2.1

```
    <root> -- nil
      |
00.00.00.00/1 (0) -- nil
      |
01.00.00.00/2 (0) -- nil
      |
01.00.00.00/3 (0) -- nil
      |
01.01.00.00/4 (0) --------------------+
      |                               |
01.01.00.00/5 (0) -- nil        01.01.10.00/5 (0) -- nil
      |                               |
01.01.01.00/6 (1) -- nil        01.01.10.00/6 (0) -- nil        
      |                               |
01.01.01.00/7 (0) -- nil        01.01.10.00/7 (0) -- nil
      |                               |
01.01.01.01 (1)                 01.01.10.01 (1)
```

Comment: What you describe (a tree where you descend the tree by checking bits of the IP in sequence) is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree.  That page says they do find use for IP routing, "where the ability to contain large ranges of values with a few exceptions is particularly suited to the hierarchical organization of IP addresses."

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting, I did not know that. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: What happens when you have an address that could be both a host address or a subnet? For instance, `1.1.1.0` could be a subnet with a `/24` mask or a host address in any mask smaller than `/24`.

Comment: @RonMaupin They would be "duplicated": the subnet would be an internal node and the host addresses leaves. You would still be able to tell them apart by looking at their position in the tree

Comment: That means this tree is going to be HUGE. It will be geometrically bigger than the number of addresses. It should have some other method to account for aggregates.

Comment: @RonMaupin Indeed, the tree should have 2^33-1 = 1+2+4+...+2^32 nodes when full. The address that you mentioned would all be located on the same path from the root to 1.1.1.0. Using n bits to navigate and nodes with 2^n children would reduce the nodes needed, but increase the search time as each node would have a set of IP addresses (the tree in my answer use n=1). Do you think this is a better approach?

Comment: Based on the OP's requirements to first match a specific IP address before looking for a range, I would have a hash table of the specific IP addresses which would quickly find whether or not the specific address exists. Next, you could look in the tree of aggregates. It doesn't make sense to store a duplicate of a host address in every one of the 32 possible subnets. Also, routing tables look for the longest match first, but it seems your tree looks for the shortest match first.

Comment: @RonMaupin I see, it definitely makes sense. Why not writing your own answer to the question then? :)

Comment: OK. I answered from my perspective. With the use of a little IPv4 math, it should be a much smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to determine some decision points.  This has to be completely deterministic.  The only decision point you have stated is that it should be checked for a host address (/32) first, then look for a shorter mask.

- Should it look for progressively shorter masks (longest match)?
- If it includes a specific mask length, do you look at shorter or
  longer mask lengths, too, or is is restricted to that mask length,
  that mask length and shorter, or that mask length and longer?  If you want to look at other lengths, do you want the longest match the way routing tables do it?
- What do you do with addresses like your example, `1.1.1.1/24`, where
  the address is longer than allowed by the mask length?  Do you assume
  it to be a host-only address (`1.1.1.1/32`), or do you look for the subnet (`1.1.1.0/24`) where the above decision points come into play?

You are going to need to get over memory consumption concerns where you need this for a few hundred million addresses with any reasonable speed.

I will assume that host addresses will the largest number of addresses you have, and, as the mask lengths become shorter, you will have progressively fewer addresses for each mask length.

If you use hash tables (one for each of the 32 mask lengths), you could start at the longest mask length (/32) table and, if the match isn't found, look at short mask length tables, depending on the deterministic rules above.

For instance, with `1.1.1.1/24` you have in your question, assume you have aggregates of `1.1.1.0/24`, `1.1.0.0/23`, and `1.1.0.0/22`.

```
Table /32
1.1.1.1

Table /31
not found

Table /30
not found

Table /29
not found

Table /28
not found

Table /27
not found

Table /26
not found

Table /25
not found

Table /24
1.1.1.0

Table /23
1.1.0.0

Table /22
1.1.0.0

Table /21
not found

Table /20
not found

Table /19
not found

Table /18
not found

Table /17
not found

Table /16
not found

Table /15
not found

Table /14
not found

Table /13
not found

Table /12
not found

Table /11
not found

Table /10
not found

Table /9
not found

Table /8
not found

Table /7
not found

Table /6
not found

Table /5
not found

Table /4
not found

Table /3
not found

Table /2
not found

Table /1
not found
```

For example, with `1.1.1.1/24`: You could start looking for the host address in the `/32` table.  If you don't find that, then `AND` the address with the mask to get `1.1.1.0` in the `/24` table.  If you don't find that, `AND` with the next shorter mask and look in that table.  Repeat until you find a match or the mask length gets to `0`.  Exactly how you do this depends on the the algorithm resulting from your decisions above.

This only takes up one 32-bit memory block for each host address or aggregate, but, with a few hundred million addresses, it won't be a small amount.  Performance will be highly dependent on the hashing algorithm used, but it should perform quite well.

Answer (score 0):

postgreSQL have support for inet, cidr addresses with built-in functions to search them (and also range type).

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/datatype-net-types.html

Not sure if that was what you are asking.